# Android : ListVIew : change background onClick

Tags: android, background, android-listview, onclicklistener

I have ListVIew , and i want to change background of items when i click on it , to show it is  selected. But when I use  this code (under text) it change every 13 items background color . example:  if i select 1 item and scroll down it will change color of each 13 item ( 1-13-26..) . And i want to change background only for one item.

```
lvpl.setOnItemClickListener( new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           TextView tv = (TextView) view
           tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(125,75,236,90));
           final_ids.add(ids.get(position));
     }
});
```

Comment: you can use a selector. are you using custom adapter?

Comment: And `final_ids` is what? Is it a member of lvpl (what is this too?) or it's an enveloping layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your adapter for list is reusing the views which are moved out of screen.

The solution is to set default color in adapter for other views

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) convertView.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.your_list_item, null);

    }
if(postion!=SelectedPosition)
  {
   convertView.setBackgroundColor(default Color);
    }
  else
   {
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(125,75,236,90));
   }



    return convertView;

}
```

Comment: how to get `SelectedPosition` here?

Answer (score 3):

You will have to set the background color for all your items in adapter.
Set some default color to all rows and then app the color to the clicked row.
But when you change color of the clicked row, make sure that the color of other rows is your default color.
Then call notifydatasetchanged() from your adapter.

Answer (score 0):

replace this line

```
TextView tv = (TextView) view;
```

with someting like this

```
TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

here `R.id.textView` is you your text view id.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass color by setting a drawable in the background of the textview and then pass that textview on the listview to show different colours of the items depending on the state of the item. You can refer to this link for more details : 
http://arshad-parwez.blogspot.in/2012/07/listview-item-highlight-when-item-is.html

Comment: @CVS : if the solution helped you, then please accept the answer. I really need to increase my repo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [listSelector property](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:listSelector) which is defined in ListView's parent class (AbsListView):

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/rd_playlist"       
    android:listSelector="@color/colorCoral"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</ListView>
```

You can also use [setSelector(..)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setSelector(int)) function to set the color programmatically:

> lvp1.setSelector(Color.argb(125,75,236,90));